# Index MYSQL table to solr 5

Tags: mysql, jdbc, solr

I am trying to make full import for mysql table to solr.
The issue is only 10 documents are indexed while the mysql table size is almost 1 million. When i debug the full-import request i always get"

```
<str name="Total Rows Fetched">10</str>
```

I am using Solr 5.
How i can solve that?

Comment: Share the data-config.xml and check the solr logs...

Comment: <dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="xxxxx"
            user="msdev"
            password="xxxx"/> 
  <document>
    <entity name="table" query="select NRCode as 'id',NRTitle as 'name' from news"  deltaQuery="SELECT NRCode as 'id' from news WHERE NRDate > '${dih.last_index_time}'" 
 deltaImportQuery="SELECT NRCode as 'id',NRTitle as 'name' from news WHERE id='${dih.delta.id}'"/>
  </document>
</dataConfig>

Comment: add the "batchSize" : The batchsize used in jdbc connection. Use a value of '-1' in case of setFetchSize()  exception.

Comment: i tried that but did not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DataImportHandler when you set "Debug" mode the default is index only 10 rows. To index more than 10 rows you can disable debug mode or set "Rows" to another value.